# Can someone please clarify my understanding of a mock's Verify concept?

Tags: .net, asp.net, mocking, moq, rhino-mocks

I'm playing around with some unit tests and mocking. I'm trying to verify that some code, in my method, has been called. I don't think I understand the `Verify` part of mocking right, because I can only ever Verify main method .. which is silly because that is what I `Act` upon anyways.

I'm trying to test that my logic is working - so I thought I use Verify to see that certain steps in the method have been reached and enacted upon.

Lets use this example to highlight what I am doing wrong.

```
public interface IAuthenticationService
{
    bool Authenticate(string username, string password);
    SignOut();
}

public class FormsAuthenticationService : IAuthenticationService
{
    public bool Authenticate(string username, string password)
    {
        var user = _userService.FindSingle(x => x.UserName == username);
        if (user == null) return false;

        // Hash their password.
        var hashedPassword = EncodePassword(password, user.PasswordSalt);

        if (!hashedPassword.Equals(password, StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
            return false;

        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, true);
        return true;
    }
}
```

So now, I wish to verify that

- `EncodePassword` was called.
- `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(..)` was called.

Now, I don't care about the implimentations of both of those. And more importantly, I do not want to test those methods. That has to be handled elsewhere. What I though I should do is Verify that those methods were called and .. if possible ... an expected result was returned.

Is this the correct understanding of what 'Verify' means with mocking?

If so, can someone show me how I can do this. Preferable with `moq` but i'm happy with anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I see it, you have two problems:

1. `EncodePassword` belongs to the `FormsAuthenticationService`, which makes it harder to mock.
   There are two possible solutions to this problem:

   1. Make EncodePassword protected virtual, and create `Mock<FormsAuthenticationService>`. In this case you should be able to `Verify` `EncodePassword`.
   2. Extract password encoding into a different service, since it is not coupled to authentication implementation anyway.
2. `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(..)` is a static method. One reasonable solution here is to use an additional service that completely wraps `FormsAuthentication`, but does not do anything beyond that, so you will not have to test it.

Answer (score 6):

You should normally (IMO, at least) be mocking dependencies rather than other methods within the class that's under test. For example, you could have an `IPasswordEncoder` interface which is used for the `EncodePassword` call. You could mock *that*, and verify that the method had been called... but within the same class it doesn't make as much sense.

I dare say many mocking frameworks *can* do this sort of mocking, but I personally wouldn't encourage it. If you've found places you want to be able to inject different functionality, consider making them separate dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

In test driven development you very rarely want to assert that a private method is called. What does verifying that the `EncodePassword` is called really test? If we look at the method in detail we see that for example I can change the method to throw away the result of the `EncodePassword` call *without breaking the test*. This is certainly not right - The test has become too flexible and is of little use. Instead consider those two ways around this.

### Tests the public interface of the class

This is what you usually want. Do you *really* care wheter that that method is called or not? The `Authenticate` method does something, we want to tests that this method does what it should. Perhaps an assert like this to test that a wrong password does not authenticate:

```
Assert.That(service.Authenticate("Pure.Krome", "wrong pass"), Is.False);
```

This allows you to *refactor* the class more easily without breaking the tests. Also the *documenting* power of the test increases - How is this class supposed to be used?

### Extract the functionality in the method into it's own class

Sometimes a private method of an class should not be called during the test, but rather mocked. For example the static method call `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, true)` may have side-effects or may throw when not run on the webserver or such. In this case my experience it's best to inject an interface describing the needed functionality. In this case for example an `ICookieTarget` with a `SetAuthCookie` method than can be mocked.